# I'm having this issue while trying to install Angular

Tags: angular

While trying to install Angular in my Windows this error keeps showing:

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Alejandro\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Alejandro\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\inquirer\\node_modules'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Alejandro\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\inquirer'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Alejandro\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\inquirer'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Alejandro\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Alejandro\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneG2WkPw
npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm run compile
npm ERR! npm ERR! > cliui@8.0.1 precompile
npm ERR! npm ERR! > rimraf build
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! "rimraf" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
npm ERR! npm ERR! programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR!
```

What I have:

Node v18.16.0
NPM 9.5.1

I've tried uninstalling Angular, clean cache, reinstalling node and npm, deleted npm folder in appdata folder, also tried from powershell. All of that with a few restarts of my computer.

What should I do?

this never happened to me before.

Comment: Please share your error message in the plain text format not image

Comment: Sorry, I updated the info. @FarkhodAbdukodirov

Comment: 1. In `Power Shell` did you try by admin mode enabled?
2. Find and delete following folders as well: 
`node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may be because of update.
You can try clearing the cache using
npm cache clean --force
and then check for cache using
npm cache verify

Then after try to perform npm install. If it doesn't work then try using force parameter
npm install --force